# Можно ли как-то избежать сокращение при записи в текстовый файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

```
def getweights(self):
    try:
        os.remove(self.datafile)
    except:
        os.mknod(self.datafile)
    finally:
        file=open(self.datafile,'w')
        file.write('{"wih":%s,"who":%s}'%(self.wih,self.who))
```

[image: weights.json]

> **Как убрать сокращение в виде 3 точек?**

Comment: Можно. Как воспроизвести вашу проблему? :) Представьте пример значения в `self.wih`. И еще вопрос, какой тип у `self.wih`?

Comment: self.wih- массив NumPy.
self.wih=np.random.normal(0.0,pow(self.hnod,-0.5),(self.hnod,self.inod))
Сейчас попробую построчно записать эти массивы думаю тогда сработает

Comment: Кст, вы ведь в курсе, что текущая запись списка в json у вас невалидная? `np` не ставит запятые между элементами

Comment: Понимаю, но построчной записью элементов это можно исправить, только пока не понятно будет считывать массив тогда или нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте вернуть не `np.array`, а `list`:

```
def getweights(self):
    try:
        os.remove(self.datafile)
    except:
        os.mknod(self.datafile)
    finally:
        file=open(self.datafile,'w')
        file.write('{"wih":%s,"who":%s}'%(self.wih.tolist(), self.who.tolist()))
```

---

**PS.**

Я бы рекомендовал работать с `json` через специальный модуль:

```
import json

...

data = {
    "wih": self.wih.tolist(),
    "who": self.who.tolist(),
}
file.write(json.dumps(data))
```

Answer (score 2):

Проблема вызвана тем, что вы пытаетесь писать в текстовый файл используя текстовую репрезантацию Numpy массива. При попытке преобразовать массив Numpy в строку вызывается метод `ndarray.__repr__()`, который обрезает массив, чтобы уберечь вас от вывода огромных массивов данных на печать - это может занять очень много времени. Для сохранения массивов Numpy в текстовый файл существует метод [np.savetxt()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html)

---

Также для хранения данных в текстовом виде и с указанием имени полей кроме JSON можно использовать CSV формат.

Пример с использованием Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd    # pip install pandas

df = pd.DataFrame({"wih":self.wih, "who":self.who})
df.to_csv(r"/path/to/filename.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: А насчет np.savetxt, там ведь нужно передавать имя файла или файлово-подобный объект (типа IOStream). Посмотрел [исходники](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.16.1/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L1186-L1434) и выходит, что если передавать файловый объект, то в него будет записан массив, но файл не будет закрыт, что позволяет использовать конструкцию вида: `f.write('{"f": ')` + `self.wih.savetxt(f)` + `f.write('}')`

Comment: @gil9red, наверное так можно сделать, но читать придется нестандартными методами... Представляю что бы обо мне подумали коллеги оставь я им такую красоту ;)